# cups print server: How to hold local and remote jobs until released?

Tags: cups

I would like to tell my cups print server to hold all print jobs until they get manually released.

Using `cupsdisable --hold <printer or class>` does pause the printer instead and `lpoptions -p <printer> -o hold-job-until=indefinite` works for locally submitted print jobs but not for remotely sent jobs. How can I configure cups to hold all jobs until they get manually released?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a configuration option for cups which does set every incoming print job on hold. I wrote a bash script instead to do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash

# cups_hold_new_jobs [<printer>]

# Resume a cups printer, set all queued and newly incoming jobs on
# hold, pause printer and exit.

# Runs as long as there are jobs in the print queue. Start from cron.

DEBUG=false


# --------- do not edit below ---------
VERSION=0.3
VERSION_INFO="(c) 2024 by Adrian Zaugg under GNU General Public License Version 3."

# initiate job list
declare -a JOBS

# set defaults
LOCK="/run/$(basename "$0")"
LOCKED=false
OWNPIDPPID="$$  $PPID   "


# get job list
function get_job_list() {
    JOBS=($(lpstat -o "$PRINTER" | sed -e 's/^\('"$PRINTER"'-[0-9]\+\).*$/\1/g'))
}


# DEBUG variable must be set to true or false
if [[ "$DEBUG" != "true" && "$DEBUG" != "false" ]]; then
    DEBUG=false
fi

# cups must be running
if [ $(lpstat -r | grep -c "is running") -eq 0 ]; then
    $DEBUG && echo "[INFO] CUPS is not running. Nothing to do." >&2
    exit 0
fi

# get printer (or class?)
PRINTER="$1"

# get default printer if none was given as an argument or check given printer name
if [ -z "$PRINTER" ]; then
    PRINTER="$(lpstat -p -d 2>/dev/null | grep "^system default destination: " | sed -e 's/^system default destination: //')"
    # check
    if [ -z "$PRINTER" ]; then
        echo "[ERROR] No printer given on command line and unable to detect default printer." >&2
        exit 1
    else
        $DEBUG && echo "No printer given on command line, using default printer: $PRINTER" >&2
    fi
else
    # no space, hash, slash or newline in printer names allowed
    PRINTER="$(echo "$PRINTER" | head -1 | sed -e "s%/.*$%%" -e "s/#.*$//" -e "s/ .*$//")"
    if [ ${#PRINTER} -lt ${#1} ]; then
        echo "[ERROR] Disallowed characters in printer name found."
        exit 1
    fi

    # check given printer exists
    ERR="$(lpstat -p "$PRINTER" 2>&1)"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        # printer does not exist or other error
        echo "[ERROR] No printer printer \"$PRINTER\" found." >&2
        exit 1
    else
        $DEBUG && echo "Using printer: $PRINTER" >&2
    fi
fi

# lock
while ! $LOCKED; do
    mkdir "$LOCK" 2>/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        LOCKED=true
        break;
    elif [ $(ps -e -o pid,ppid,command | sed -n "s/\([0-9]\{1,\}\)[^0-9]\{1,\}\([0-9]\{1,\}\)[^0-9]\(.*\)$/\1\t\2\t\3/p" | \
             grep -v "$OWNPIDPPID" | grep -cE 'bash .*/'"$(basename "${0}")"'$') -gt 1 ]; then
        # process already started
        $DEBUG && echo "Another instance of this script is already running." >&2
        exit 0
    else
        # stale lock, remove it
        rmdir "$LOCK" 2>/dev/null
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "[ERROR] Removing stale lock $LOCK failed." >&2
            exit 1
        else
            $DEBUG && echo "Removed stale lock." >&2
        fi
    fi
done

# pause printer
if [ $(lpstat -p "$PRINTER" | grep -c -m 1 "$PRINTER disabled") -eq 0 ]; then
    cupsdisable "$PRINTER"
    $DEBUG && echo "Printer paused." >&2
fi
PRINTER_PAUSED=true

# loop as long as there are jobs in the queue
get_job_list
until [ ${#JOBS[@]} -eq 0 ]; do

    # find index of last held job in new job list
    last_held_job_index=0
    unset job_id
    while [[ "${JOBS[$last_held_job_index]}" != "$last_held_job_id" && $last_held_job_index -le ${#JOBS[@]} ]]; do
        last_held_job_index=$(($last_held_job_index+1))
    done
    if [ $last_held_job_index -eq ${#JOBS[@]} ]; then
        # job not found
        last_held_job_index=-1
    fi

    # set newly queued jobs on hold
    i=0
    for job_id in ${JOBS[@]}; do
        # compare index to marker of last held index
        if [ $i -gt $last_held_job_index ]; then
            # set job on hold
            ERR="$(lp -i "$job_id" -H hold 2>&1)"
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo -e "[INFO] holding job $job_id" >&2
            else
                echo "[ERROR] Failed to hold job \"$job_id\": $ERR" >&2
            fi
            # remember last index
            last_held_job_index=$i
        fi
        i=$(($i+1))
    done
    last_held_job_id="${JOBS[$last_held_job_index]}"

    # wait a bit
    sleep 1

    # reread jobs in print queue
    get_job_list

    # enable printer now
    if $PRINTER_PAUSED; then
        cupsenable "$PRINTER"
        PRINTER_PAUSED=false
    fi
done

# queue is now empty disable printer
if $PRINTER_PAUSED; then
    $DEBUG && echo "Queue is empty." >&2
else
    cupsdisable "$PRINTER"
    echo "[INFO] Queue is empty now, pausing printer $PRINTER." >&2
fi

# unlock
if $LOCKED; then rmdir "$LOCK"; fi

exit 0
```

The script pauses the printer upon start, sets all existing jobs on hold, does the same for newly incoming jobs, unpauses the printer and waits until the queue gets empty. Upon exit it pauses the printer again.

The idea is that the print jobs can get released or canceled by their owners manually (or automatically canceled by the cups setting MaxHoldTime). This is one part of a simple pull printing system.

It is a first version of the script, it suffers under a race condition, must be called by cron, is lacking a help text, is not tested for classes, asf. If I ever add functionality or fixes I will post a [download link](https://ente.limmat.ch/ftp/pub/software/bash/cups/) in this answer. Use it on your own responsibility. Do not use in production, it is here to give an idea how it can be done.

**It would be great to hear of a simpler way to tell cups to set all incoming jobs on hold** to build up a follow-me-printing system without a bloat of additional software.

---

**Download**:
Copying the above fails, because tabs might get lost, use the
download link: https://ente.limmat.ch/ftp/pub/software/bash/cups/